# Kernel error during installation of Ubuntu 20.04 or 18.04 on MSI B450 GAMING PRO CARBON AC / AMD Ryzen 7 2700

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel, uefi, msi

### I have a problem when I'm trying to boot Ubuntu 18.04 from USB flash drive.

---

```
 My operating system is:

1.  OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
2.  Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363
3.  Other OS Description    Not Available
4.  OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
5.  System Name DESKTOP-J9ES8JV
6.  System Manufacturer Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
7.  System Model    MS-7B85
8.  System Type x64-based PC
9.  System SKU  To be filled by O.E.M.
10. Processor   AMD Ryzen 7 2700 Eight-Core Processor, 3200 Mhz, 8 Core(s), 16 Logical Processor(s)
11. BIOS Version/Date   American Megatrends Inc. 1.C0, 6/11/2020
12. SMBIOS Version  2.8
13. Embedded Controller Version 255.255
14. BIOS Mode   UEFI
15. BaseBoard Manufacturer  Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
16. BaseBoard Product   MSI B450 GAMING PRO CARBON AC (MS-7B85)
17. BaseBoard Version   1.0
18. Platform Role   Desktop
19. Secure Boot State   Off
20. PCR7 Configuration  Binding Not Possible
21. Windows Directory   C:\Windows
22. System Directory    C:\Windows\system32
23. Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume2
24. Locale  United States
25. Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "10.0.18362.387"
26. User Name   DESKTOP-J9ES8JV\Traveller
27. Time Zone   GTB Standard Time
28. Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 32.0 GB
29. Total Physical Memory   32.0 GB
30. Available Physical Memory   29.0 GB
31. Total Virtual Memory    37.0 GB
32. Available Virtual Memory    32.6 GB
33. Page File Space 5.00 GB
34. Page File   C:\pagefile.sys
35. Kernel DMA Protection   Off
36. Virtualization-based security   Not enabled
37. Device Encryption Support   Reasons for failed automatic device encryption: TPM is not usable, PCR7 binding is not supported, Hardware Security Test Interface failed and device is not Modern Standby, Un-allowed DMA capable bus/device(s) detected, TPM is not usable
38. Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions    Yes
39. Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions   Yes
40. Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware    No
41. Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection Yes
42. Samsung SSD 970 EVO 500GB Partition style: GUID Partition Table (GPT)
43. My graphics card is Sapphire VGA Radeon RX 590 8GB Nitro+.
44. RAM PATRIOT PVS432G320C6K VIPER STEEL SERIES 32GB (2X16GB) DDR4 3200MHZ DUAL KIT
```

---

**SSD : Samsung MZ-V7E500BW 970 Evo 500gb V-Nand Nvme Pcie Gen 3.0 X4 M.2 2280**

**GPU: Sapphire VGA Radeon RX 590 8GB Nitro+.**

**Ram: Patriot PVS432G320C6K Viper Steel Series 32gb (2x16gb) Ddr4 3200mhz Dual Kit**

**Processor: AMD Ryzen 7 2700 Eight-Core Processor, 3200 Mhz, 8 Core(s), 16 Logical Processor(s)**

**Mother Board: MSI B450 GAMING PRO CARBON AC (MS-7B85)**

### And the error witch appears is:

[error which appears in the screen and freezes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKDyv.jpg)

```
[ 986.927967] *(detected by 9, t=195022 Jiffies, g=-515, q=88) 
[ 986.929391] Sending NMI from CPU 9 to CPUs 5: 
[ 986.931790] NMI backtrace for cpu 5 
[ 986.931790] CPU: 5 PID: 533 Comm: systemd-udevd Tainted: G D 5.4.0-42-generic #46-18.04.1-Ubuntu
[ 986.931791] Hardware name: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. MS-7885/8450 GAMING PRO CARBOP AC (MS-7B85), BIOS 1.CO 06/11/2020
[ 986.931791] RIP: 0010:native_queued_spin_lock_slowpath+Ox1a3/0x1f0 
[ 986.931791] Code: 03 83 ee 01 48 c1 e0 05 48 63 f6 48 05 00 ba 02 00 48 03 04 f5 20 e9 a3 ba 48 89 10 8b 42 08 85 c0 75 09 f3 90 8b 42 08 85 C0 <74> f7 48 8b 02 48 85 c0 74 8b 48 89 c6 0f 0d 08 eb 89 8b 07 85 c0
[ 986.931791] RSP: 0018:ffffa267c061fe90 EFLAGS: 00000046 
[ 986.931792] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff91fa64879980 RCX: 0000000000190000 
[ 986.931792] RDX: ffff91fa9e96ba20 RSI: 0000000000000005 RDI: ffff91fa68f6a100 
[ 986.931792] RBP: ffffa267c061fe90 ROB: 0000000000180000 R09: 0000000000000000 
[ 986.931793] R10: ffffa267c0667d90 R11: 000000000000b794 R12: 0000000000000009 
[ 986.931793] R13: 000000000000664c R14: ffff91fa68e545c0 R15: 0000000000000000 
[ 986.931793] FS: 00007ffa0c359680(0000) GS:ffff91fa9e940000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000 
[ 986.931793] CS: 0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CRO: 0000000080050033 
[ 986.931794] CR2: 00007ffa0be2cb52 CR3: 00000007e5bda000 CR4: 00000000003406e0 
[ 986.931794] Call Trace: 
[ 986.931794] _raw_spin_lock_irq+0x26/0x2a 
[ 986.931794] acct_collect+Ox9e/0x190 
[ 986.931794] do_exit+0x196/Oxb80 
[ 986.931794] ? _raw_spin_lock_irq+0x26/0x2a 
[ 986.931795] rewind_stack_do_exit+0x17/0x20 
[ 986.931795] RIP: 0033:0x7ffa0be2cb7c
[ 986.931795] Code: Bad RIP value.
[ 986.931795] RSP: 002b:00007fff3d408c70 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000038
[ 986.931796] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 00007fff3d408c70 RCX: 00007ffa0be2cb7c
[ 986.931796] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000001200011
[ 986.931796] BP: 00007fff3d408d20 ROB: 00007ffa0c359680 R09: 0000000000000000
[ 986.931796] R10: 00007ffa0c359950 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
[ 986.931797] R13: 0000000000000020 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 000055930bc7e040
```

### I tried to switch places over Ram and another message with a problem appeared.

```
amip gpio_generic 
[ 12 807896] CR2: 0000000000000000 
[ 12 809172] ---[ end trace 258325aed8b23411 ]— 
[ 12.810497] RIP: 0010:dm_read_reg_func+Oxlg cx90 [amdgpu] 
[ 12.811802] Code: b3 f4 90 66 2e Of if 84 00 00 00 00 00 Of 11 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 41 56 41 55 41 54 53 48 89 fb 48 8b 7f 18 41 89 f4 48 8b 07 <48> 8b 00 e8 2b d7 89 f5 41 89 c6 0f 1f 44 00 00 5b 44 89 f0 41 5c
[ 12.813219] RSP: 0018:111faa7b405284178 EFLAGS: 00010046 
[ 12 814605] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff92fbba672e00 RCX: 0000000000000013 
[ 12.816017] RDX: ffffffffc07c7090 BSI: 0000000000001bcf RDI: ffff92fbba666030 
[ 12.817447] RBP: ffffaa7b40528d98 ROB: 0000000000000007 R09: 0000000000000013 
[ 12.818888] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000001bcf 
[ 12.820335] R13: 0000000000001bcf R14: ffff92fbba667080 R15: ffff92fbab365f98 
[ 12.821796] FS: 0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff92fbbebc0000(0000) knIGS:0000000000000000 
[ 12.823281] CS: 0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CRO: 0000000080050033 
[ 12.824777] CR2: 0000000000000000 CR3: 00000007ea8dc000 CR4: 00000000003406e0 
[ 11 12 826295] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
[ 12.894545] AMD-Vi: Completion-Wait loop timed out 
[ 12.896077] Kernel Offset: 0x34200000 from Oxffffffff81000000 (relocation range: Oxffffffff80000000-Oxffffffffbfffffff) 
[ 12.897641] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt ]---
```

[here i have Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JasYf.jpg)

### And sometimes it goes until this step and freezes

[frozen screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hLdF.jpg)

---

The funny thing is that I have installed the Ubuntu in my laptop, I dual boot it and it's work fine also in my other PC.

I have tried the latest version of Ubuntu 20.04 also and it's not working

My MSI Motherboard has those 2 options in the bios menu 'legacy+UEFI' and 'UEFI'

I have already the latest bios from my vendor.

I cannot access kernel options I have a freeze problem.

Comment: Possible clues to try:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519758/amd-vi-completion-wait-loop-after-a-failed-install-of-arch-linux-on-a-blank-ssd  It looks like the IOMMU could be causing the issue.  Upon booting to the USB add the `iommu=off` to the kernel options.

Comment: Also check for any firmware/BIOS updates offered by the vendor.

Comment: Do not turn legacy on, if Windows is UEFI. MSI B450 Tomahawk Max & MSI Nvidia GTX 1080 TI UEFI update & defaults
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2450961
MSI Tomahawk B350 with Ryzen R5 1600 New UEFI required
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390475
If nVidia you need safe boot or nomodeset and install nVidia driver during install.

Comment: I cannot access kernel options to set `iommu=off`, but I did it from bios. The result was that now I have only Kernel error on the screen.
I have already the latest bios from my vendor.
I don't have the option to select only Legacy, only the combination of Legacy and UEFI or UEFI, it is on Legacy and UEFI but in the msinfo32 is shows 14. BIOS Mode UEFI.
My graphics card is Sapphire VGA Radeon RX 590 8GB Nitro+.
I tried to install another version of Linux like mint and the error it's the same.

Comment: See:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions and in the section "Changing the CD Boot Option Configuration Line" follow that and add the `iommu=off`.  There might be other things to try like what the F6 options offer like `acpi=off`.